# How to send object through href and receive it in the Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to ask you if it is possible in Spring MVC to send a complete object through the href in the view, and receive it in the comtroller.

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">   
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/SpringSample1/editStudent?${student}">${student.id}</a></td>
        <td>${student.name}</td>
        <td>${student.email}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editStudentGet(@RequestParam("student") Student student, ModelMap model) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid adding the entire `Student` object into the generated HTML page and then sending it back to the server.

Most likely, the `Student` object are from a database or some other persistent store. If so it makes more sense to build the URL for the `href` attribute with just the student ID. The controller will then receive the ID and fetch or otherwise reconstruct the `Student` object.

Comment: You are right but, for "educational" purposes I am wondering if it is posible to move the whole objet.